# C# ASP.NET MVC Remote Validation doesn't work / doesn't get called

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use a remote validation in order to check if email already exists. I've been struggling for about an hour so it's about time to post a question.

`EmployeeController.cs`:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult employeeExists(string Email)
{
       bool emailExists = dataAccessLayer.emailExists(Email);

       if(emailExists)
           return Json(true);

       return Json(false);
 }
```

`Employee.cs` (model):

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
[Remote("employeeExists", "Employee", AdditionalFields = "Email", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "Email address already registered.")]
[Display(Name = "Email")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

Function of data access layer -> `emailExists()`:

```
public bool emailExists(string emailToSearch)
{
    Employee employee = new Employee();

    using (SqlConnection mConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand mCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT count(*) FROM employees WHERE email=@email", mConnection);
        mCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", emailToSearch);

        mConnection.Open();
        SqlDataReader mSqlDataReader = mCommand.ExecuteReader();

        if (mSqlDataReader.HasRows)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if it's a typo - a case sensitive thing - or am I missing something?

EDIT 1 :

Scripts that are included in the view :

```
<script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/js/site.js?v=ji3-IxbEzYWjzzLCGkF1KDjrT2jLbbrSYXw-AhMPNIA"></script  
<script src="/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js">/script>
```

In view i call the scripts through :

```
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Comment: check if unobtrusive  validation js and other required js files are configured to be loaded

Comment: What error are you getting? The action you specified in your `Remote` attribute ('employeeExists') does not match the actual action of `emailExists`. You may also need to specify, on your action, the verbs it accepts -> `[AcceptVerbs("Post")]`

Comment: Have you enabled client validation and unobtrusive javascript in your settings or global.asax?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Updated question - those are the scripts that are called on the "Create view" (which has a form and email input)

Comment: @SBFrancies i call the scripts but i don't know something about `global.asax` - should i check? (updated question)

Comment: The data annotation on the class is: `[Remote("employeeExists", ...`, however, your method is called `emailExists` ...... which is it now??

Comment: always use `Url.Content`for js,css, images paths

Comment: `if (mSqlDataReader.HasRows)` doesn't one row always exists? in case if email wasn't found you will receive `0`. Use `ExecuteScalar`

Comment: have a look  at :http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f1047f/check-if-usernameemail-already-registered-using-remote-vali/

Comment: @marc_s `[Remote("employeeExists",...` calls the `public JsonResult employeeExists(string Email)` and inside that function there is another one - through an access later which uses `emailExists` - i just changed them all at `emailExists` but nothing happened

Comment: @DmitryPavliv no need to worry yet abou the SQL, i have tried using `return Json(true)` on the first line of `employeeExists` - in order to check if it's triggered and nothing happens with that.

Comment: 1) put breakpoint in the `employeeExists` method - check if it is called. 2) in your browser open `Network` tab and check if request have been send

Comment: don't see ref to `"~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"`

Comment: @DmitryPavliv it is triggererd! where can i download that? haven't read anywhere i need an `unobtrusive-ajax.js`

Comment: @DmitryPavliv i downloaded through NuGet but it does not appear in my project, therefore can not use it? `Microsoft.Jquery.Unobtrusive.Ajax`

Comment: @DmitryPavliv, `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` is for use with the `@Ajax.*` helpers and has nothing to do with client side validation.